# html5 canvas. document.onkeypress arrow keys not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a simple HTML5 Canvas football game. The game has three options, The player chooses left, right or centre to kick a ball, the goal keeper is random and will dive left, right or stay in the centre. I want the user to press the left, right or up arrow keys to trigger the player to kick the ball but I can't get my code to recognise when the arrow keys are pressed. I have tried different keys which will work ie, the return key.

```
function canvasApp(){   

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        //Other Var's

        document.onkeypress = function doKeyDown( e ) {
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if ( key == 37  ){
                userChoice = key;
            } else if (key == 38){
                userChoice = key;
            } else if (key == 39){
                userChoice = key;
            }
        }

        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );             
            //------------------------------------------------
            //Player shoots left
            if ( userChoice == 37 ){
                //More code
            //------------------------------------------------
            //Player shoots right
            } else if ( userChoice == 39 ){
                //More code
            //------------------------------------------------
            //Player shoots centre
            } else if ( userChoice == 38 ) {
                //More code
            }

            //------------------------------------------------
        }

        function gameLoop(){
            window.setTimeout(gameLoop, framerate);
            draw()
        }
        gameLoop();
    }

    document.onclick = function( e ){
        window.clearTimeout();
    }
```

If you need to see the full code let me know and I'll put a link up to a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're triggering the wrong event: use **keydown** even instead:
Check this page: http://help.dottoro.com/ljlkwans.php

The following is a snippet with jquery: if you use the **keypress** event it does not work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).keydown(function(e){
            var key = e.keyCode;
            if ( key == 37  ){
                console.log("left");
            } else if (key == 38){
                console.log("center");
            } else if (key == 39){
                console.log("right");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: glad to hear it! You should then mark mine as the correct answer if you think it fits.